# Flink Xpack ElasticSearch 5 ElasticsearchSecurityException missing autentication

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, xpack

Goodmorning everyone. I am trying to Flink connector Elasticsearch 5.2.1 and I have problems with the authentication XPACK

Comment: Can you add some more details on the problems you are facing?

Comment: Hello, I want to connect to Elasticsearch and I'm using the connector Flink 
`code config.put("cluster.name", "my-application");
    config.put("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");
    List<InetSocketAddress> transportAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
    transportAddresses.add(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    input.addSink(new ElasticsearchSink<>(config, transportAddresses, new ElasticsearchFlink())); ` 
I installed XPack and when I try to connect gives me this error:
`code Caused by: ElasticsearchSecurityException [missing authentication token for action`

Comment: I saw that in /org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/elasticsearch5/Elasticsearch5ApiCallBridge.java class is used _new PreBuiltTransportClient (settings);_ instead of _new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient (settings)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different transport clients is currently (March 2017, Flink 1.2) not supported in Flink.

However, I've filed a JIRA to add the feature: [FLINK-6065
Make TransportClient for ES5 pluggable](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6065)

Until this has been implemented into Flink, I recommend overriding the `ElasticsearchSink` and using a different call bridge calling the `PreBuiltXPackTransportClient`.