# Flink with ElasticSearch 5 Sink conflicts of io.netty library

Tags: netty, apache-flink, elasticsearch-5, xpack

I am playing with flink+ElasticSearch 5 Sink, using x-pack authentication.

I got this error first
[Flink Xpack ElasticSearch 5 ElasticsearchSecurityException missing autentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807454/flink-xpack-elasticsearch-5-elasticsearchsecurityexception-missing-autentication)

So i fixed it overwriting the ES Sink function.

My problem now is when I try to run the job on flink (using the jar) I got this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponents(ZLjava/lang/Iterable;)Lio/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf;
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.toByteBuf(Netty4Utils.java:78)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:422)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.sendMessage(Netty4Transport.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.internalSendMessage(TcpTransport.java:1058)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.sendRequestToChannel(TcpTransport.java:1040)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.executeHandshake(TcpTransport.java:1555)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:502)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.connectToNode(TcpTransport.java:460)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:354)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:312)
    at com.ceptinel.flink.sink.Elasticsearch5ApiCallBridge.createClient(Elasticsearch5ApiCallBridge.java:45)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkBase.open(ElasticsearchSinkBase.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:375)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:251)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:670)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks there is a conflict on the library io.netty between flink and ES client (not sure if is the x-pack-transport or the connector itself)

Any workaround to avoid this conflict?

Thanks
Luis

Answer (score 1):

Until this is fixed in Apache Flink (by shading the netty dependency away), I recommend you to shade netty in your user jar into a different namespace.

If you are building your project with Apache Maven, you can use the `maven-shade-plugin` to do it.
Also check this documentation page on shading in Flink: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#resolving-dependency-conflicts-with-flink-using-the-maven-shade-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes that was I was trying to do, I guess that I am not doing the shading properly. I will doble check it.

Comment: Feel free to post your shading stuff somewhere (new SO question), I can then review it if you want.

Comment: I am trying to do something like:<pattern>io.netty</pattern>
                                                                              <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.client.dependencies.io.netty</shadedPattern>

Comment: That's almost correct. Did you also include netty into the `<artifactSet>`?

Comment: Update: In Flink 1.4, netty will be shaded away.

Answer (score 1):

I am using gradle instead of maven but the process is more or less same.

In case, if you still have this issue (which is highly unlikely), I have tried solving and the solution seems to work.

Here is my dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile(group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.10', version: project.flinkStreamJavaVersion)
            {
                exclude group: 'io.netty'
            }
    compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka-0.10_2.10', version: project.flinkKafkaConnectorVersion
    compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.10', version: project.flinkElasticConnectorVersion

    ....
}
```

and then shaded io.netty into a different package using:

```
shadowJar {
    ....
    relocate 'io.netty', 'shaded.io.netty'
    ....
}
```

**Note: The catch is to exclude netty coming from**

```
flink-streaming-java_2.10
```

If you try to shade without excluding the netty coming from flink-streaming it won't change anything. So it is very important to exclude the netty coming from flink-streaming lib.